# Проект gradle не собирается, error: failed linking references

Tags: android-studio, gradle

У меня в drawables был файл backgroundCustom.png. Понятия не имею как я его туда засунул и не заметил заглавную букву. Спустя месяц хотел запустить проект, ас жаловался на регистр конечно же, при смене регистра или удалении файла пишет ошибку, которую никак не могу пофиксить.
Чистил кэш, проект, пересобирал проект. Всё без толку. И выходит патовая ситуация, при наличии файла он ругается на регистр, при отсутствии ошибка ниже.
Сам файл нигде в проекте не используется.

Ошибка:

Android resource linking failed
com.project.tori.app-mergeDebugResources-43:/values/values.xml:2227: error: resource drawable/backgroundCustom (aka com.project.tori:drawable/backgroundCustom) not found.
com.project.tori.app-mergeDebugResources-43:/values/values.xml:2227: error: resource drawable/backgroundCustom (aka com.project.tori:drawable/backgroundCustom) not found.
error: failed linking references.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил, нужно было просто проверить тщательно файл styles.xml.